# android what to worry about when deprecated API still working in higher API version

Tags: android, api

Made an app targeting API8 and it's running fine 
on all emulator images all the way up to API15.

I cannot test the app on other higher apis so I'm not
setting the `android:targetSdkVersion`.

What about this deprecated warnings:

```
android.view.Display.getHeight()

This method is deprecated.
Use getSize(Point) instead.
```

Can I ignore this and just keep on using `Display.getHeight()`?

I read about reflection or programmatically testing what Android version the device is using.

Why do people do that when it's working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot test the app on other higher apis so im not
>   setting the android:targetSdkVersion.

If you are testing "on all emulator images all the way up to API15", then you are "test[ing] the app on other higher apis".

> Can i ignore this and just keep on using Display.getHeight()?

In Android, "deprecated" usually means "we have a better solution that you should consider using, but we will keep the deprecated one working as long as we can". Sometime after you drop support for API Level 12 and down, you might wish to move to `getSize()`. For now, `getHeight()` should work fine on all Android API levels.

> Why do people do that when it's working for me?

They do not do that for deprecated APIs. They use version checks and the like for accessing things that simply do not exist in older versions of Android, so they do not try referring to non-existent APIs on older devices.